# ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle in apache

Tags: python, oracle, apache, flask

I deploy flask with apache on CentOS7

And I want Oracle database to insert or select when user access.

So I install cx_Oracle

```
pip install cx_Oracle
```

And run flask on virtual env.

```
flask run
```

It work with no error.

But I access to localhost:80 using apache, It occur Internal Server Error 500.

In error_log

```
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:34.623473 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 475] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:35.678302 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 510] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:35.681622 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 510] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:35.681665 2020] [core:notice] [pid 510] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:38.074902 2020] [:error] [pid 513] [client 172.17.0.1:33640] mod_wsgi (pid=513): Target WSGI script '/var/www/hitme/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:38.074946 2020] [:error] [pid 513] [client 172.17.0.1:33640] mod_wsgi (pid=513): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/hitme/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:38.074973 2020] [:error] [pid 513] [client 172.17.0.1:33640] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:38.074994 2020] [:error] [pid 513] [client 172.17.0.1:33640]   File "/var/www/hitme/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:38.075058 2020] [:error] [pid 513] [client 172.17.0.1:33640]     from app import app as application
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:38.075070 2020] [:error] [pid 513] [client 172.17.0.1:33640]   File "/var/www/hitme/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:38.075138 2020] [:error] [pid 513] [client 172.17.0.1:33640]     import cx_Oracle
[Fri Oct 23 09:12:38.075162 2020] [:error] [pid 513] [client 172.17.0.1:33640] ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle
```

I followed this article for deploy flask with apache.

https://dev.to/sm0ke/flask-deploy-with-apache-on-centos-minimal-setup-2kb7

and install cx_Oracle and I copied it where I thought I needed it.

Here my tree

```
 /etc/httpd/modules/
              |-cx_Oracle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
              |-cx_Oracle-8.0.1.dist-info

/var/www/hitme/lib/python3.6/site-packages
                                |-cx_Oracle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
                                |-cx_Oracle-8.0.1.dist-info

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
                                |-cx_Oracle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
                                |-cx_Oracle-8.0.1.dist-info
```

But it still gives the error.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Are you sure Apache is running the expected version of Python?  The log message mentions 2.7.5 but your tree shows 3.6.  Do you really need to copy cx_Oracle?  My notes on a non-Apache setup are at [How to use Python Flask with Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-to-use-python-flask-with-oracle-database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the required  Oracle Instant Client is installed to the Apache user by downloading

https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/199000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.9.0.0.0dbru.zip

and unzip ut to a folder Apache user owns or is accessible for read and execute - lets say

```
/apache/oracle
```

After that, ensure PATH, ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH ist set properly as Apache User - i.e.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/apache/oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
```

If you start Apache as service then you may need to set the variables to root or user who starts apache.

Comment: Please DO NOT suggest setting ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client. It can cause network files not to be located.  And with Apache, environment variables are typically scrubbed, so it's  a lot  better to use ldconfig instead of setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Finally, the error is that cx_Oracle is not found, not that the Instant Client can't be found.